# got stuck in recursive relation

Tags: recursion, expected-value

i was solving an expected value problem but i got stuck in finding recursive relation?

recursive equation is...
$$
E[n-i]=1+\frac{i}{n}E[n-i-1]+\frac{n-i}{n}E[n-i+1]
$$

- $E[0]=0$
- $E[1]=1$
- $E[2]=4$

I know it a non homogeneous eqation so there will be perticular solution and general solution.
i will appreciate if somebody help me out.

Comment: If I let $n=2$ and $i=1$, your conditions don't fit the recursive equation.

Comment: If $i=0$ we have $E[n]=1+E[n+1]$.  Is that intended?